# Making a matrix multiplication work in parallel java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

Ive created this code from what i have been taught to create a matrix multiplication.

But i want to parallise this code so it works on multiple threads.

Could someone help/do this for me please? Im quite unsure how to do it!

Updated:

```
public class ParallelMatrix {
    public final static int N = 1000; //Random size of matrix

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Create and multiply matrix of random size N.
        double[][] a = new double[N][N];
        double[][] b = new double[N][N];
        double[][] c = new double[N][N];

        int i, j, k;

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                a[i][j] = i + j;
                b[i][j] = i * j;
            }

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                pool.submit(new Multi(N, i, j, a, b, c));
            }
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Calculation completed in " +
                (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
    }

    static class Multi implements Runnable {
        final int N;
        final double[][] a;
        final double[][] b;
        final double[][] c;
        final int i;
        final int j;

        public Multi(int N, int i, int j, double[][] a, double[][] b, double[][] c) {
            this.N = N;
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate each cell of Matrix C in a separate thread, for example:

```java
class Multi implements Runnable {
    final int N;
    final double[][] a;
    final double[][] b;
    final double[][] c;
    final int i;
    final int j;
    ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    }
}
```

```java
ExecutorService pool = ...;
for (int i = 0;...)
for (int j = 0;...)
pool.submit(new Multi(N, i, j, a, b, c));

pool.shutdown();
pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Makes more sense to do it for whole columns or rows though.

Comment: This is what i am to do, how would i split my code up to add this to it? Could you provide the code would really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I alredy provided you with the code. Just fill the for loops like in your original code, and complete the constructior.

Comment: Okay let me see how far i get, ive never used ExecutorService so was getting confused

Comment: Im having no luck keep getting errors when adding my loops in.

Comment: The errors probably tell you what is wrong. I am not going to write the whole code for you. I gave you all the important parts and just feel the gaps. If you have concrete error on which you are stuck, write it and I can help.

Comment: Its telling me variable N is not initialised when i add this, im sorry about asking you for the whole code, i am a beginner and am just trying to save some time, i apologise.

Comment: N is declared on top of your Matrix class. Take the code starting with ExecutorService and place it in your main method instead of the second banch of fors that did the calculations. The Runnable class can be either inner inside your Matrix class (but outside the main method) or as a separate class in its own file. Its constructor has to initilize all the parameters, N, i,j...)

Comment: Okay understand much better now think i almost got it

Comment: It is not. You keep calculating the array the old way inside your for loop. The exact loop structure is in my code. It has only one statement, submission of the job. Waiting for all the computations to finish must be of course outside the loop as in my code. If you want parallel than you need to use more than one thread in the pool.

Comment: Okay so the pool = the number of threads, it needs more than 1 to work in parallel. I understand that now. Inside the pool ive followed your loop structure. I hope the updated is now better, slowly getting there now.

Comment: The exact loop structure is in my code. It has only one statement, submission of the job.

Comment: oooooooooohh! I see! Is the loop above the pool fine?

Comment: the loop above the pool has nothing to do with the multiplication. It is you setting up the input tables.

Comment: Yes thats what i thought..Just getting one last problem, RejectedExecutionException is an error i get when trying to run the program

Comment: Could you kindly read carefully my comments please. The shutdow and awaiting must be after the loop. You were given the exact code for that part

Comment: I apologise, i am just very unfamiliar with multithreading. I have updated the code, is that better?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW here is an alternate method using Java Streams API. There's probably better ways to implement parallel matrix multiplications, especially using BLAS libraries and GPU implementations like jcuBLAS. But if you need vanilla Java then this would be an option.

```java
static double[][] multiplyStreams(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
  assert a.length == b.length;
  assert a.length > 0;
  assert a[0].length == b[0].length;
  assert a.length == a[0].length; // just work on square matrices

  int N = a.length;

  double[][] result = new double[N][N];

  IntStream.range(0, N).parallel().forEach(i ->
    IntStream.range(0, N).parallel().forEach(j ->
      IntStream.range(0, N).forEach(k ->
        result[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
      )
    )
  );

  return result;
}
```

Notes: Comparing the original method from @Ali Mohammad and the Streams version, the Streams version is slightly faster on my machine:

```
Calculation completed in 1187 milliseconds
Streams calculation completed in 963 milliseconds
```

Code for comparison:

```java
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
double[][] d = multiplyStreams(a, b);
endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Streams calculation completed in " +
        (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
```

You can also extend the code to make it generic for any [M x K][K x N] matrix multiplication.